# EntityManager.remove() does not generate delete query and does not remove entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have the following tables: BOOK, AUTHOR and AUTHOR_BOOK. AUTHOR_BOOK is used for referencing the many to many relationships between book and author, and it holds two fields: author_id and book_id.

So in my test program, I first added a new book with new author that both are not in the database, and then query the new book with my Service implementation, the returned Book object is correct, but when I tried to pass it into my deleteBook() method in my service, the book was not deleted and there were no deletion SQL generated in the logs. There was also no errors or exceptions at all in my logs so I have no idea what went wrong :(

Here are the class files (only posted parts that I think are relevant)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Book.findAllWithDetails",
                query = "select distinct b from Book b left join fetch b.authors a left join fetch b.category c"
        ),
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Book.findBookById",
                query = "select distinct b from Book b left join fetch b.authors a left join fetch b.category c where b.id = :id"
        )
})
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "bookResult",
        entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = Book.class)
)
public class Book {
    private Long id;
    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private Float price;
    private Category category;
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

    public Book() { }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "author_book",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
    public Set<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }

    public void setAuthors(Set<Author> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    public void addAuthor(Author author) {
        authors.add(author);
        //author.addBook(this);
    }

    public void removeAuthor(Author author) {
        authors.remove(author);
        //author.removeBook(this);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String description;
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    public Author() { }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "author_book",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
    public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

//    public void addBook(Book book) {
//        getBooks().add(book);
//    }
//
    public void removeBook(Book book) {
        getBooks().remove(book);
    }
}

Service("jpaPublishingService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PublishingServiceImpl implements PublishingService {
    private final String ALL_BOOK_NATIVE_QUERY = "select id, title, isbn, price, category_id from book";
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PublishingServiceImpl.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    // use namedQuery
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Book> findAllBooksWithDetails() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Book.findAllWithDetails", Book.class).getResultList();
    }

    // use namedQuery
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Book findBookByIdWithDetails(Long id) {
        TypedQuery<Book> query = em.createNamedQuery("Book.findBookById", Book.class);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }

    // save using JPA2
    @Override
    public Book createNewBook(Book book) {
        if (book.getId() == null) {
            logger.info("Inserting new book");
            em.persist(book);
        } else {
            em.merge(book);
            logger.info("Updating existing book");
        }
        logger.info("Book saved with id: " + book.getId());
        return book;
    }

    // delete using JPA2
    @Override
    public void deleteBook(Book book) {
        Book mergedBook = em.merge(book);
        em.remove(mergedBook);
        logger.info("Book with id: " + mergedBook.getId()  + " deleted successfully");
    }
}
```

Please let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the book object without merging it(use em.find), it works for me.

```
public void deleteBook(Book book) {
        // Book mergedBook = em.merge(book);
        Book b1=em.find(Book.class,book.getId);
        em.remove(b1);
        logger.info("Book with id: " + mergedBook.getId()  + " deleted successfully");
    }
```

Comment: I tried but it output an error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance com.yzhan.bookapp.domain.Book"

Comment: really sorry, i forgot the em.find